# MySQL calculate only the row-differences for rows in the same group

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (call it trans):

```
issue_id:   state_one:  state_two:  timer:      
1           A           B           1
1           B           C           3

2           A           B           2
2           B           C           4
2           C           D           7
```

I'd like the get the difference in 'timer' between consecutive rows, but only those with the same issue_id.

Expected result:

```
issue_id:   state_one:  state_two:  timer:    time_diff:                 
1           B           C           3         2

2           B           C           4         2
2           C           D           7         3
```

When taking the time difference between two rows, I'd like the result displayed next to the later row.

If we only had one, time-ordered issue in the table, the following code works fine:

```
select 
    X.issue_id, 
    X.timer as X_timer,  
    Y.timer as Y_timer, 
    (X.timer - Y.timer) as time_diff
from trans X
cross join trans Y
where Y.timer in (
    select 
        max(Z.timer)
    from trans Z
    where Z.timer < X.timer);
```

I want to generalize this approach to handle MANY issues with time-ordered state changes.

My idea was to add the following condition, but it only works if consecutive events belong to the same issue (not the case in the real world):

```
... where Z.timer < X.timer)
and X.issue_id = Y.issueid;
```

Question: In MySQL, can I do this iteratively (i.e. calculate differences for issue_id=1, then for issue_id=2, and so on)? A function or subquery?

Other strategies? Constraint: I have read-only privileges. I truly appreciate the help!

EDIT: I added expected output, added a row to my example table, and clarified.

Comment: Not very clear. What result you are expecting? For example, 'issue_id=1, result=2'.

Comment: (1) Can you give expected output. I assume in this case it should be `null`,`2`,`null`,`2` but please confirm.
(2) For same `issue_id`, how the order should be determined? Based on `state_one`,`state_two`?. In case `state*` are same then how should you proceed?

Comment: *It's clear how to get the difference between rows if they're ordered* How?

Comment: @Andrew, apologies, I added my expected result

Comment: @Utsav, you are correct. I'm happy to keep a null in time_diff for the first row of an issue, or just omit the row in my result (which I've edited my question to show).

My ordering logic for the input table is: order by issue_id, timer. 
For the output, the order doesn't matter to me. Each row will tell me the time the issue spent in a state.

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming timer or (issue_id,timer) is PRIMARY...

```
SELECT a.*, a.timer-MAX(b.timer)
  FROM trans a
  JOIN trans b
    ON b.issue_id = a.issue_id
   AND b.timer < a.timer
 GROUP
    BY a.issue_id
     , a.timer;
```

Comment: this is brilliant. I just wrote out the join+group by on a piece of paper and my head exploded, thank you!! I also see why you need timer to be a primary key. In the case of my real world problem, an issue may have multiple identical timestamps (this solution will only return one of two rows with equivalent timestamps). No problem, I will clean my table to exclude duplicate timestamps prior to running this.

Comment: Glad it helped. A trick that sometimes helps to understand what a GROUP BY clause is doing is to write out the same query with an ORDER BY instead of a GROUP BY, and without the aggregate functions (So `SELECT a.*,b.timer, etc... ORDER BY a.timer`)

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
issue_id, (MAX(timer)-MIN(timer)) as diff from trans
group by issue_id
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. Unfortunately, I oversimplified my example (I've since edited it). There are often more than 2 rows per issue, so max-min won't capture all of the transitions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from #Temp

Select T1.Issuerid,T1.stateone,T1.statetwo,MAX(T1.timer)-MIN(T.timer) as  Time_Diff from #Temp T1
left join #Temp T2 on
T1.issuerid=T2.IssuerId
group by T1.Issuerid,T1.stateone,T1.statetwo
```

Please Give me Reply

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for your answer. It works for the example I originally provided. Unfortunately, my original example was oversimplified (many issues will have more than 2 rows).

Comment: Hi ojdajuiceman thanks for your reply I will look forward for this at get back to you with a suitable query for  you.